# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'context')

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

when I start develop the google chrome extension app using this command in macOS Monterey:

```
npm run dev
```

shows error like this:

```
   [2] ./src/public/fontello/font/selection-translator.woff 71 bytes {0} [built]
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--8-1!node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!src/options/options.scss:
    Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
    [0] ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--8-1!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/options/options.scss 598 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

    ERROR in ./src/options/options.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--8-1!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/options/options.scss)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'context')
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/crx-selection-translate/node_modules/css-loader/lib/loader.js:101:58)
        at Array.map (<anonymous>)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/crx-selection-translate/node_modules/css-loader/lib/loader.js:99:31)
        at /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/crx-selection-translate/node_modules/css-loader/lib/processCss.js:199:3
```

I have searched from internet seems no one facing this problem. this is the project `package.json`:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/crx-selection-translate.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "xpostinstall": "node ./build/install-pdf-viewer",
    "dev": "webpack --config build/webpack.dev.config.js",
    "build": "gulp --cwd . --gulpfile build/gulp-build.js",
    "test": "karma start build/karma.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.1",
    "chrome-call": "^1.0.2",
    "connect.io": "^3.1.3",
    "interact.js": "^1.2.6",
    "translation.js": "github:jiangxiaoqiang/translation.js",
    "vue": "^1.0.24",
    "vue-router": "^0.7.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.5.0",
    "chrome-env": "^0.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "download": "^5.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-jsonmin": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "gulp-zip": "^3.2.0",
    "isparta-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
    "karma": "^6.3.11",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-coveralls": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "1.6.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.6",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "sass": "^1.22.10",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  },
  "author": "Jiangxiaoqiang <jiangtingqiang@gmail.com>",
  "license": "GPLv3",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/crx-selection-translate/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/crx-selection-translate#readme"
}
```

I have tried to remove the `node_modules` folder and reinstall dependencies but could not fix the problem? what should I do to fix this problem? and this is my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require( 'webpack' );
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require( 'mini-css-extract-plugin' );

module.exports = {
  entry : {
    bg : './src/background-scripts/' ,
    content : ['./src/content-scripts/firefox-fix.js', './src/content-scripts/'] ,
    options : [
      './src/options/'
    ],
    popup : './src/popup/' ,
    'bs-lite' : './src/public/bootstrap-lite.scss'
  } ,
  output : {
    path : path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/bundle') ,
    filename : '[name].js'
  } ,
  module : {
    rules : [
      {
        test : /\.js$/ ,
        exclude : [ /node_modules(?!(\/|\\?\\)(translation\.js|selection-widget|connect\.io|chrome-env)\1)/ ] ,
        loader : 'babel-loader'
      } ,
      {
        test : /\.woff$/ ,
        loader : 'file-loader' ,
        query : {
          name : '[name].[ext]'
        }
      } ,
      {
        test : /\.html$/ ,
        loader : 'vue-html-loader'
      } , 
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test : /\.(scss)$/ ,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoader: 2
            }
          },
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons1: {
          name: 'commons1',
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 1,
          test(module,chunks){
            for (const chunk of module.chunksIterable) {
              if (chunk.name && /(popup|content)/.test(chunk.name)) {
                   return true;
              }
            }
            return false;
          }
        },
        commons2: {
          name: 'commons2',
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 1,
          test(module,chunks){
            for (const chunk of module.chunksIterable) {
              if (chunk.name && /(options|commons1)/.test(chunk.name)) {
                   return true;
              }
            }
            return false;
          }
        },
        commons3: {
          name: 'commons3',
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 1,
          test(module,chunks){
            for (const chunk of module.chunksIterable) {
              if (chunk.name && /(bg|commons2)/.test(chunk.name)) {
                   return true;
              }
            }
            return false;
          }
        },
      }
    }
  },
  plugins : [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, it says your problem is in `./src/options/options.scss`